# I was working on this project for real time face mask detection, but the i am facing an error cannot reshape array of size 2 into shape (1,100,100,1)

Tags: arrays, numpy

Please tell me so as to what should i do to solve this problem or what values should i put to solve this problem

while(True):

```
ret,img = source.read()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces=face_clsfr.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)

for x,y,w,h in faces:
    face_img = gray[y:y+w,x:x+w]
    resized = cv2.resize(face_img,(100,100))
    normalized=resized/255,0
    reshaped = np.reshape(normalized, (1,100,100,1))
    result=model.predict(reshaped)
    
    label=np.argmax(result,axis=1)[0]
    
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h), colordict[label],2)
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y-40),(x+w,y), colordict[label],-1)
    cv2.putText(img,labels_dict[label], (x,y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.8,(255,255,255),2)
    
cv2.imshow('Frame',img)
key=cv2.waitKey(1)

if(key=='q'):
    break
```

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
source.release

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You change the array type of image to a tuple in:

```
normalized = resized/255,0
```

change to:

```
normalized = resized/255
```